# PHP array remove characters and keep only the numbers

Tags: php, arrays

looking for the code can remove characters from the array and display numbers only.

```
array( 
    1=>123456 hello; / &, 
    2=>128767 ^% * ! ajsdb, 
    3=>765678 </ hello echo., 
);
```

i want to remove the floowing from the array

```
hello; / &
^% * ! ajsdb
</ hello echo.
```

and wants to keep as stated

```
array( 
    1=>123456, 
    2=>128767, 
    3=>765678, 
);
```

Thanks and Kind Regards,

Comment: you will need a regular expression for that

Comment: Would this happen to be *homework*?

Comment: Are those even valid array elements?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use preg_replace to replace all non-numeric chars with ''

```
$arr = array(
    1 => "1234 perr & *",
    2 => "3456 hsdsd 3434"
);

foreach($arr as &$item) {
    $item = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $item);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

results in

```
array(2) { [1]=> string(4) "1234" [2]=> &string(8) "34563434" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a for statement to get values of your array and try this:

```
    foreach($arr as $value){
        $cleansedstring = remove_non_numeric($value);
        echo $cleansedstring;
    }


function remove_non_numeric($string) {
return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

// Set array
$array = array( 
    1 => "123456 hello; / &", 
    2 => "128767 ^% * ! ajsdb", 
    3 => "765678 </ hello echo.",
);

// Loop through $array
foreach($array as $key => $item){
    // Set $array[$key] to value of $item with non-numeric values removed
    // (Setting $item will not change $array, so $array[$key] is set instead)
    $array[$key] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $item);
}

// Check results
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function number_only($str){
    $slength = strlen($str);
    $returnVal = null;
    for($i=0;$i<$slength;$i++){
        if(is_numeric($str[$i])){
            $returnVal .=$str[$i];
        }
    }
    return $returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `preg_replace` using `[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$values = array(
    1=>"123456 hello; / &",
    2=>"128767 ^% * ! ajsdb",
    3=>"765678 </ hello echo",
);

$number_values = array();
foreach($values as $value) {
    $pieces = explode(' ', $value);
    $numbers = array_filter($pieces, function($value) {
        return is_numeric($value);
    });

    if(count($numbers) > 0)
    {
        $number_values[] = current($numbers);
    }
}

print_r($number_values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to take a look at the intval method (http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and the foreach loop (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

With those 2 functions combined you will be able to clear all the elements from the not numeric characters,

Answer (score 0):

Why not `array_walk()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

```
$arr = array(
    1 => "1234 perr & *",
    2 => "3456 hsdsd 3434"
);

array_walk($arr, function(&$item) { 
    $item = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $item);
});

print_r($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1234
    [2] => 34563434
)
```

Check it online:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d63d07e58f9ed6984f96eb0075955c7b36509f81